# Write a function to remove rows that contain specific strings

Tags: python

Hi I have the dataset below:

```
    Name    ID_NB       Rule_F 
0   Alice   1715386     PDF FORMAT   
1   John    17172319    PDF-DDD   
2   Mark    14819611    PDF   
3   Sarah   14881611    PDF FORMAT   
4   Dee     846620760   PDF FORMAT
```

I would like to remove all the rows that contain "PDF-DDD" and "PDF", this is my code and it doesn't remove anything:

```
def remove_string(merged_ouput):
    """delete row if Rule_Name contains list_string"""

    list_string = ["PDF-DDD", "PDF"]
    for k in merged_output.Rule_F:
        for e in list_string:
            if e in k:
                remove(k)

    return merged_output

print(merged_output)
```

Expected output:

```
    Name    ID_NB       Rule_F 
0   Alice   1715386     PDF FORMAT     
1   Sarah   14881611    PDF FORMAT   
2   Dee     846620760   PDF FORMAT
```

Could you please help? thank you !!

Comment: Are you using `pandas` here?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `print(remove_string(merged_output) or is there something missing from your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Alice', '1715386', 'PDF Rule'],
    ['John', '17172319',  'PDF-DDD'],
    ['Mark', '14819611', 'PDF'],
    ['Sarah', '14881611', 'PDF Rule'],
    ['Dee', '846620760', 'PDF Rule']
], columns=['Name', 'ID_NB', 'Rule_Name'])
print(df)

Name      ID_NB Rule_Name
0  Alice    1715386  PDF Rule
1   John   17172319   PDF-DDD
2   Mark   14819611       PDF
3  Sarah   14881611  PDF Rule
4    Dee  846620760  PDF Rule

list_string = ["PDF-DDD", "PDF"]
res = df[~df['Rule_Name'].isin(list_string)]
print(res)

Name      ID_NB Rule_Name
0  Alice    1715386  PDF Rule
3  Sarah   14881611  PDF Rule
4    Dee  846620760  PDF Rule
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
df.where((df['Rule_Name'] != 'PDF') & (df['Rule_Name'] != 'PDF-DDD')).dropna()
```

That is of course if you're using pandas dataframe
If not, what's the type of your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't remove 'k' from 'merged_output'.Check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `merged_output` before `remove(k)`. And there is no need to iterate list_string because `in` checks if it matches one of the strings in the list anyway.

This should return a new List with only the Rows which don't contain one of the list_string's for Rule_F

```
[k for k in merged_output if k.Rule_F in list_string]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
df = df[~df["Rule_F"].isin(["PDF", "PDF-DDD"])]
print(df)
```

Which yields

```
    Name      ID_NB      Rule_F
0  Alice    1715386  PDF FORMAT
3  Sarah   14881611  PDF FORMAT
4    Dee  846620760  PDF FORMAT
```